# Moving with MEAN stack to Linux from Windows

Tags: angularjs, linux, node.js, windows, mean-stack

From last few months our team is developing a web app using MEAN stack (mongoDB Express AngularJS NodeJS) on Windows8.1.

We used Express4.0. We're ready for production. Suddenly stockholders requested us to shift complete development to RHEL 7 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7).

Would like to discuss few points:

- Is it good to move on RHEL 7 ?
- What are the breaking changes ?
- How to migrate from Windows to Linux ?

Any other point, I missed and beneficial for us.

All responses in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about server engine? You didn't plan to just start node.js and use it without any proxy, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is what you call platform independent, so if you automated your start scripts you should be good there. RHEL 7 is one of the top linux distributions, it's well documented and if you have linux experience it's easy to master. If your team does not have linux experience then you are in a little bit of a jam.

From the top of my head

- How will you demonize node.js process, and what will bring it back up
  if it crashes
- How will your MongoDB scale?
- How will my app scale?
- What will we use as a reverse proxy for incoming requests? (nginx)
- Can my team handle it? Do we have someone who is a system engineer?